# AFTER ALTER ON DATABASE gives the old password value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, passwords, alter

I am writing a trigger to fetch the 'password' value when 'sys.users$' table gets updated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER Sys_User_Nm_Trg AFTER ALTER ON DATABASE
WHEN (ora_dict_obj_type = 'USER')
DECLARE

CURSOR get_pw IS
SELECT password
FROM sys.user$
WHERE name = ora_dict_obj_name;

user_pw_ VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

IF (ora_dict_obj_name != 'SYS' AND ora_dict_obj_name != 'SYSTEM') THEN
  IF (ora_des_encrypted_password IS NOT NULL) THEN

 OPEN get_pw;
 FETCH get_pw INTO user_pw_;
 CLOSE get_pw;


 END IF;
END IF;

END;
/
```

But this cursor gives the old 'password' not the changed 'password' value. But if I run

```
SELECT password
FROM sys.user$
WHERE name = ora_dict_obj_name;
```

in a separate transaction it gives the correct changed value. Is there something that I should change in the trigger to fetch the updated value for the password?